# How do I access data on my EBS Volume from R-Studio Server on Ubuntu EC2 Instance

Tags: aws, rstudio

I have setup R-Studio Server on an Ubuntu EC2 instance for the first time and successfully started r-studio server in my browser. I also have putty ssh client. How do I set path in r-studio server to my mounted EBS volume and why do I not see the contents of my EBS volume in the r-studio files area (bottom right side? ) . Also, I had a file in an s3 bucket. I passed this command to bring it from s3 to my ebs volume: `s3cmd get s3://data-analysis/input-data/filename.csv` . I assume this command downloads the file from s3 into the ebs volume. But I can't find it in RStudio Server! I have scoured the internet looking for help on this but not able to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this question got up-voted so someone else is looking for the answer. Here it is:

I was logged in as the default user on Ubuntu instance when i did the

```
$s3cmd get s3://data-analysis/input-data/filename.csv
```

The data got saved from the s3 bucket to the home directory of the user named ubuntu. this can be verified with :

`$ df -h /home/ubuntu/`

Since I had followed [randy zwitch's tutorial](http://randyzwitch.com/r-amazon-ec2/) on installing R on aws - i had created a user named rstudio and that was the user name I was using to log-in to rstudio server. Hence I had to move the file from the default 'ubuntu' user's home directory to the user 'rstudio'. this can be done with:

`$ sudo mv /home/ubuntu/filename.csv /home/rstudio`

Happy to answer follow up questions.